# Set non-null values of DataFrame conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
     0         1         2   3         4  y
35 NaN       NaN       NaN NaN  0.342153  0
40 NaN  0.326323       NaN NaN       NaN  0
43 NaN       NaN  0.290126 NaN       NaN  0
49 NaN  0.326323       NaN NaN       NaN  0
50 NaN  0.391147       NaN NaN       NaN  1
```

And code to produce it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame(
{0L: {35: nan, 40: nan, 43: nan, 49: nan, 50: nan},
 1L: {35: nan,
  40: 0.32632316859446198,
  43: nan,
  49: 0.32632316859446198,
  50: 0.39114724480578139},
 2L: {35: nan, 40: nan, 43: 0.29012581014105987, 49: nan, 50: nan},
 3L: {35: nan, 40: nan, 43: nan, 49: nan, 50: nan},
 4L: {35: 0.34215328467153283, 40: nan, 43: nan, 49: nan, 50: nan},
 'y': {35: 0, 40: 0, 43: 0, 49: 0, 50: 1}})
```

I need to assign a value to each column using the following pseudocode:

```
column = 1 if column > threshold else 0 where column != NaN
```

I have tried using fancy indexing to accomplish this like so:

```
df.ix[df[1].notnull(),1] = 1; df

     0   1         2   3         4  y
35 NaN NaN       NaN NaN  0.342153  0
40 NaN   1       NaN NaN       NaN  0
43 NaN NaN  0.290126 NaN       NaN  0
49 NaN   1       NaN NaN       NaN  0
50 NaN   1       NaN NaN       NaN  1
```

But A) I'm not sure how to apply the conditional logic and B) I have to apply the logic to each column iteratively rather than to the dataframe as a whole.

**Question:**

> How can I apply conditional logic to the non-null values of a dataframe, preserving the nullity of the other fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# you need this because your y column is an int64 (otherwise this the next step
# will throw an exception), on the to fix list in 0.11-dev though
In [71]: df = orig_df.astype('float64')

# use boolean indexing!
# NaN are automatically excluded
In [72]: df[df>0.3] = 1 ; df[df<=0.3] = 0

In [73]: df
Out[73]: 
     0   1         2   3   4  y
35 NaN NaN       NaN NaN   1  0
40 NaN   1       NaN NaN NaN  0
43 NaN NaN         0 NaN NaN  0
49 NaN   1       NaN NaN NaN  0
50 NaN   1       NaN NaN NaN  1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `applymap`, since it seems like you really want an elementwise operation:

```
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: x if pd.isnull(x) else (1 if x > 0.3 else 0))
     0   1   2   3   4  y
35 NaN NaN NaN NaN   1  0
40 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  0
43 NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN  0
49 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  0
50 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  1
```

Although in this particular case we could cheat (twice):

```
>>> (df > 0.3) * 1 + df * 0
     0   1   2   3   4  y
35 NaN NaN NaN NaN   1  0
40 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  0
43 NaN NaN   0 NaN NaN  0
49 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  0
50 NaN   1 NaN NaN NaN  1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `iterrows()` method. [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows)

I wasn't 100% sure on what you were trying to accomplish with the pseudo-code, but the following would modify the new series (which can be assigned to the data frame).

```
updated = df['data']
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if ((not pd.isnull(df[index])) and df[index] > threshold) :
        updated[index] = 1.0
    else:
        updated[index] = 0.0
df['data'] = updated
```

It will most likely give you a `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning about assignment in the iterator as well, so use with caution.